# Visual Studio Shortcut to that ComboBox above

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a shortcut or to set a new one which allows me to open that current source code navigation combobox from above without using my mouse. Is there such a thingy? I mean the combobox at the top that shows us all the methods and members from the currently opened source file in VS. Any suggetions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> , and the use <kbd>tab</kbd> to navigate

you can also change this shortcut via Tools -> Options -> Enviroment -> Keyboard and then search for Window.MovetoNavigationBar

Comment: I have Ctrl-F8 so it might depend on what settings (C++/C#/..) were selected on the first run after installation?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I know already about ctrl + f2 buuut is there a way not to always use tab to skip 2 steps until you focused the right combobox